# SVG working on webpage but not as an embedded .svg file

Tags: svg

I am trying to load an SVG from a .svg file. When I copy the SVG code into the webpage itself, it works. However, it doesn't work when I load the SVG code from a .svg file.

### This works:

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg height="100" width="100">
      <polygon points="0,40 60,40 60,100 40,100 40,60 0,60" style="fill:lime"/>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

### This does not work:

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <object data="pic.svg"></object>
  </body>
</html>
```

**pic.svg:**

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <polygon points="0,40 60,40 60,100 40,100 40,60 0,60" style="fill:lime"/>
</svg>
```

Even using

```
<img src="pic.svg"/>
```

does not work.

Why does this happen? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: please try `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  height="100" width="100">` instead of  `<svg height="100" width="100">`

Comment: This works! Thank you! Can you please explain why it does work when including xmlns in an answer?

Comment: Please read more about [Declaring namespaces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course)